# How do keywords in Google Webmaster Tools affect search results?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords

I've checked the keywords list on the Google Webmaster Tools account for my website (which is a message board), and I noticed that the top keywords are things such as "topic" and "forum". I'm guessing that is because those are the words which appear the most within the homepage.

The question is, will this impact search results? I'm guessing yes. If so, can this be solved, and how? I already searched on Google and on SEO forums without any luck. (When it comes to SEO, most info looks like bogus to me. I hope I'm wrong, but meanwhile I'll ask here since it seems a reliable place.)

Answer (score 1):

No. That is just a report of the keywords that are most prominent in your website. It's there to help you understand how Google sees your site.

Those keywords being prominent in your website will result in your website ranking better for those words. If you don't want those words to be the most prominent to search engines, and want other keywords to be so, then you need to rewrite your content in a way that emphasizes the words you want to be more prominent.

Comment: with "in a way that emphasizes" do you mean putting them in headers or bold tags, perhaps?

Comment: @pt2ph8 That's one way to do it. Using them in headings, page titles, throughout the content (appropriately) are other ways. [See this question for more in basic SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google).